# Building a window.location.href passing a query string

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to build window.location.href passing a 1 entry query string.

The MVC action method expects that entry to be an integer.

I can hardcode a '2' and it works. Of course I do not want to hardcode.

So I get the value and set a variable and attempt to pass that variable using either of the 2 cases below but it fails. I get:

```
{0}The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'blogCategoryId' of non-nullable type 
'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult BlogsForMaintIndex(Int32)' in 
'GbngWebClient.Controllers.AdminFunctions.BlogMaint.BlogMaintController'. An optional parameter must 
be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
```

---

How do I build it properly?

---

Here is the JavaScript:

```
  $(function () {
    $('#buttonClose').on('click', function () {
        $('#modalView').modal('hide');

        // The action method expects an integer.
        var blogCategoryId = @Convert.ToInt32(Session["BlogCategoryId"]);

        alert('blogCategoryId: ' + blogCategoryId);

        // WORKS!
        //window.location.href = "/BlogMaint/BlogsForMaintIndex/?blogCategoryId=2";

        // Neither of these 2 work.

        //window.location.href = "/BlogMaint/BlogsForMaintIndex/?blogCategoryId=blogCategoryId";

        window.location.href = "/BlogMaint/BlogsForMaintIndex/?blogCategoryId=' + blogCategoryId + '";
    })
})
```

Here is the simplified action method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult BlogsForMaintIndex(int blogCategoryId)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
let myurl = "/BlogMaint/BlogsForMaintIndex/?blogCategoryId=" + blogCategoryId;

window.location.href = myurl;
```